# Should a class named `User` be an implementation of Singleton Pattern?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, singleton

Today I read a lot of articles about how Singleton Pattern is bad, such as

1. violating single responsibility principle
2. inability to subclass
3. inability to use abstract or interface classes
4. High coupling across the application
5. make unit test difficult

And then I remember I have a program with a class named `User` which has field `userName` and `password` and something else related to `User`. In my conceive the program should only have one user instance, which is created when a human logins in my program. Based on this, should I insist design `User` class as Singleton Pattern, or is there any good design conceive I should use?

---

Additionl:

Another doubt. Using Singleton Pattern, I can get the only instance `myUser` everywhere. If I should not go with Singletion Pattern, How should I get the only instance `myUser`?

Comment: Unless kittens die, you usually don't need to *enforce a single instance and provide global access to it*. You control your application objects, so just create the User *once and only once* instead. Likewise, you usually don't need global access to the object when you use Dependency Injection instead.

Comment: Hint: I would first find a new name for that class; it is very counter-intuitive that a **User** class should have only one instance. In other words: wouldnt it make more sense to have a class User for all users; and a special class (or maybe even a singleton) called *CurrentUser* or something like that?!

Comment: @GhostCat Good advice, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look at [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).  These days there exist many frameworks to assist you with wiring of the dependency injections so that you can specify in the framework that you expect a certain object to behave like a singleton. In other words if another object also requires the same "singleton" object, the framework should not create a new instance, but "inject" the already existing instance.

If you develop in Java, you may for example look at the way Guice did it: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes  They allow you to specify whether you want to create an "eager singletons" (created even if not needed yet) or "lazy singletons" (created on the fly only when required).  Even if you are not using Java other programming languages got similar concepts that you could look out for.

What I would suggest is that you make the "User" object not a singleton and "inject" your "User" object into the classes that requires the "User" object.  If possible, let the dependency injection framework of your choice handle the wiring so that you do not accidentally create more than one instance.

This way you will still be able to achieve most of the above mentioned advantages you posted in your question and still enjoy the benefits of a "singleton".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your context. If your application must have one and only one User, then use Singleton pattern. Your 5 points mentioned will be completely counter-productive.

In your example, this is not the case. But just one and only one instance is mandatory for the execution of one process. You should take in account @Koning response then.

For example, Spring security implements some common patterns of user logged with static methods :

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext(). getAuthentication()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you look at Microsoft memberhship than you will see that they store all data on session level. The best way I see to implement such logic which will be stored on all session level is Singleton pattern, because you won't need two classes working with user data. As alternative you can use static classes, but you couldn't serialize your user data in this case